# Why a semisimple Lie algebra is always isomorphic to a subalgebra of special linear algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Significance), every semisimple Lie algebra is a subalgebra of the special linear Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ for some $n\ge 1$. But I do not know any proof of this, nor am I able to imagine an intuitive reason for this remarkable fact. Can you give me a hint or an indication on how to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over a field $\Bbbk$ with characteristic $0$. According to [Ado's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem), $\mathfrak g$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra $\mathfrak s$ of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$. But $\mathfrak{gl_n}$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$: it's the subalgebra which consits of matrices of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}M&0\\0&-\operatorname{tr}(M)\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, with $M\in\mathfrak{gl}_n$.

Comment: In characteristic $0$, we do not even need to use the (neat!) fact that $\mathfrak{gl}_n \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$. Rather, if $\rho: \mathfrak{s} \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ is any Lie algebra homomorphism, then $im(\rho) \subseteq \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$. Because in char. $0$, semisimple LA's are perfect, i.e. every element can be written as sum of commutators; so since $\rho$ is a homomorphism, every element in its image can be written as a sum of commutators, but commutators of elements of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ are in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ over any field $K$ has trivial center, because the solvable radical is zero, the adjoint representation is faithful. So we obtain an embedding of Lie algebras
$$
L\hookrightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\hookrightarrow\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}(K),
$$
without refering to Ado's Theorem, or Iwasawa's Theorem for prime characteristic.

Comment: I prefer this answer for using much less machinery than the other, and working in any characetristic. Unfortunately, my argument that the image of any representation is automatically contained in $\mathfrak{sl}$, see comment to other answer, would not work in positive characteristic, or would it?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you! I know that a semisimple Lie algebra need not be a direct sum of ideals in characteristic $p$, and that then the Lie algebra need not be perfect. You have pointed this out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397280/semi-simple-lie-algebra-l-coincides-with-its-derived-algebra-l?noredirect=1&lq=1), with reference to Sakellar, Remark 2.2. on page $9$. On the other hand, the embedding using the trace seems very elementary and is a good argument, I think.