# Is the trace preserved (up to scaling) by Lie algebra homomorphisms (between matrix Lie algebras)?

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, trace

Suppose $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism between matrix Lie algebras $V$ and $W$. Since $V$ and $W$ are real vector spaces of matrices, we can consider the traces of their elements.

My question is, do we have $\operatorname{tr} \phi(X) = \lambda\cdot\operatorname{tr} X$ for some $\lambda\ne 0$? If not, is there a good counterexample?

I am thinking we can choose a basis $\{E_{1}, \ldots, E_{n}\}$ for $V$, take $F_{j} := \phi(E_{j})$ for all $j$, and then consider structure constants
$$ [E_{i}, E_{j}] = c_{ijk}E_{k} $$
where we sum over repeated indices (Einstein summation notation).
Since $\phi$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism, we have
$$ [F_{i}, F_{j}] = c_{ijk}F_{k}. $$
By taking the traces, and noting that the trace of commutators is zero, we find
$$ c_{ijk}e_{k} = 0 \qquad\text{ and }\qquad c_{ijk}f_{k} = 0 $$
where $e_{k} := \operatorname{tr} E_{k}$ and $f_{k} := \operatorname{tr} F_{k}$.

Now my idea is to note that the $c_{ijk}$'s are determined, and our question is simply what is the null space / kernel of the $n^{2}\times n$ matrix $C = (c_{ij, k})$ ($ij$ determine row; $k$ determines column), but it's not clear how to proceed from here, or if this approach is any good to begin with. Unfortunately, I don't know of many non-trivial matrix Lie algebra examples at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are abelian Lie algebras, then any linear map $V\to W$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism.  So, for instance, if $V$ is some vector space of commuting matrices (say, all the diagonal matrices, or all matrices that are polynomials in some given matrix), you are asking whether *every* invertible linear map $V\to V$ preserves the trace up to scaling.  This is obviously false as long as $V$ contains two linearly independent elements with nonzero trace, since an invertible linear map can (for instance) scale those elements by different factors.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the endomorphism of $M_1(k)\times M_1(k)\subseteq M_2(k)$ that multiplies the elements in the first factor by $2$ and the ones in the second factor by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the other answers it is important to note that the trace is not really an intrinsic thing on the Lie algebra. A single Lie algebra can viewed as a matrix Lie algebra in a number of ways (effectively we are just picking a faithful representation) and the trace of an element in different representations will vary.

If, for example, the Lie algebra is semisimple we have a lot of control over the possible traces. Indeed they are always zero (see Torsten's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554851/why-a-semisimple-lie-algebra-is-always-isomorphic-to-a-subalgebra-of-special-lin)).

If however the Lie algebra is abelian we have no control whatsoever and the traces can be anything.